# My System has no PPCNVCOM.EXE in the OFFICE12 folder?

Tags: windows, conversion, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2003

I used Wordconv.exe to convert some .doc to .docx files, and I need to do the same to convert .ppt to .pptx files.

I have a many I would like to convert using the command line, so using Power Point program to do them one at a time is too slow.

I need ppcnvcom.exe to do this, which I believe *should* be in my OFFICE12 folder, but it is not. I have searched on the internet and have found 50,000 websites wanting me to download their "registry fixes", etc, but nowhere where I can download the original ppcnvcom.exe file.

Anyone know where I can get it? I have licences for Office 2003 and 2007, but only 2007 is installed on my dev machine.

Comment: You can't open Power Point, then file > open the ppt file, then "save as" pptx?

Comment: It depends how many files need converting I guess. :) 'ppcnvcom' allows you to do it on the command line so it's quick for batch conversions.

Comment: @Moab Yeah, except that I only need to do it to about 20,000 files ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I had found a solution to his project a few months ago :)

Comment: D'oh, scroll down.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find ppcnvcom.exe in the [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/923505/how-to-install-the-microsoft-office-compatibility-pack-so-that-you-can-open-and-save-office-open-xml-formats-in-earlier-versions-of-microsoft-office) for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint.